# Add attachment to JIRA issue using jira rest api in php curl request

Tags: php, jira, attachment, jira-rest-api, php-curl

I am using Jira rest API to create an issue with attachment. I have created issue ticket successfully with summary and description but I am facing issues in adding an attachment with Jira issue.

how can I add an attachment to Jira issue using rest API in PHP curl request?

i am using this code to add an attachment.

```
 $url = 'https://domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/PL-113/attachments';
$fileLocation = 'D:/xampp/htdocs';
$fileName = 'test.jpg';

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$data = array('file'=>"@{$fileLocation};filename={$fileName}");
$headers = array(
    'X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck'
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
$ch_error = curl_error($curl);

if ($ch_error) {

    echo "cURL Error: $ch_error";
} else {

    echo $result;
}

curl_close($curl);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: tried checking the docs or github? I assume it should be there https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Questions/JIRA-How-to-add-attachment-for-issues-using-REST-API-PHP/qaq-p/80626

Comment: Its important to do some form of research before posting questions. a copy and paste of your question yields ample answers, code snippets etc.

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi please check it, I have updated with my code. I have searched a lot on the Atlassian community also but I could not find any solution using this Php curl request.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the baseUrl you used in the sample, I assume you are working with Jira Cloud. Given the issue ID, you can add attachments by calling [Add attachment REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/#api-api-2-issue-issueIdOrKey-attachments-post).

Comment: thanks for your help @Ian.

I have tried it many times but could not succeed, I have tried 2 3 solutions from Atlassian community but still did not get any success that how to upload attachment. I placed the image in the same folder and upload but still the same issue.

can you please guide me more about it?

Comment: I am not well versed with PHP curl but via CLI, this worked for me `curl -D- -u username:password -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: no-check" -F "file=@/file/location/image.png" https://domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/TEST-3/attachments`. I'm thinking, you only need "'file'=>"@{$fileLocationWithFileName}".